# SQL - Get Count

Tags: java, mysql, sql, select, count

I have a table called COMPANIES that contains info on different companies. How do make a query that gets the company state(COMPANY_STATE) and the company name(COMPANY) count of the most used state (COMPANY_STATE) which has the highest number of different COMPANIES in it. So say Ohio has the most companies in it with 50. How to I query the database to get the state

```
| COMPANY_STATE | COUNT | 
+---------------+-------+
|      OH       |  50   |
+---------------+-------+
```

Can i do this via query or do i have to have my java program actually do the work?

Table.sql

```
CREATE TABLE COMPANIES (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    COMPANY  varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    COMPANY_CODE  char(10) NOT NULL,
    COMPANY_ADDRESS  varchar(255),
    COMPANY_STATE  char(2) NOT NULL,
    COMPANY_WORKFORCE  INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

Comment: write an SQL query using count on state and order it

Comment: Oh yeah, i could do just order, and then limt 1 right. Thanks @HussainAkhtarWahid'Ghouri'

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid'Ghouri' but how do i bring out the state name?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How do i do a count of a group by ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COMPANY_STATE, COUNT(ID) FROM COMPANIES
GROUP BY COMPANY_STATE
ORDER BY COUNT(ID) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: DESC LIMIT 1; for the top one, but yeah this is correct. Thanks